# ipywidgets align items and font style

Tags: python, user-interface, ipywidgets

Hi I am trying to align the item "See more" to the left under the dropdown and change the font style to italic, but for some reason I cant:

[image]

I have the following code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact
from ipywidgets import Box, GridspecLayout, Layout, HTML
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

selector = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=file_names,
    value=file_names[0],
    description='Choose options:',
    disabled=False,
    center = 'left',
    style = style
)
    
refresh_files_button = widgets.Button(
        description='Refresh options',
        disabled=False,
        icon="fa-refresh"
)

see_files_button = widgets.Button(
        description='See more',
        disabled=False,
        button_style='', # 'primary', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
        layout=Layout(height='20px', width='200px',justify_content="flex-end"),
        icon='fa-search-plus',
        style=dict(font_style='italic',
                    button_color='transparent')

)
grid = GridspecLayout(2,2, 
               height='80px', 
               width='500px',
            #    justify_items='center',
            #    align_items='center'
               )
grid[0,0] = file_selector
grid[0,1] = refresh_files_button
grid[1,0] = see_files_button
display(grid)
```